# Does “pivot up” exist?

Tags: phrases

I want to describe the movement that a person sits up from a lying-down position, pivoting on his/her hip, and the upper body is sort of drawing a half circle in the air.

I know there exists “pivot around”, but I don’t think that’s exactly what I’m looking for.

Can I say “pivot up”? Does it exist or what do you suggest to use to describe that movement?

I searched around the Internet and didn’t see much information about “pivot up”...

Hope someone can help. Cheers. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can say that. Pivoting is always around some position or axis, but you can use various words to indicate the direction of rotation: up, left, clockwise... Think of "pivot" as "rotate".

> Verb: **pivot**  pi-vut
>
> Turn on a pivot
>
> - swivel
>
> Noun: **pivot**  pi-vut
>
> 1. The person in a rank around whom the others wheel and manoeuvre
>
>    - pivot man
> 2. Axis consisting of a short shaft that supports something that turns
>
>    - pin
> 3. The act of turning on (or as if on) a pivot
>
>    "the golfer went to the driving range to practice his pivot"

-- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=pivot)